# jquery easyui tree drag drop & enter

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, tree, enter

i am using tree & treegrid of query plugin : http://www.jeasyui.com/demo/index.php
i wanted drag n drop functionality which currently exist, but the problem is i want to COPY node instead of MOVING it. 
Also i want to edit node of treegrid on double click & save on ENTER. I am able to edit node on dbl click but dnt knw how to capture ENTER event!!
below is  code that i have implemented for editing node:

```
<table id="bomSubTree"  style="width:600px;height:300px"> </table>
.......                 

$('#bomSubTree').treegrid({
     height: 550,
     //width:600,
     dnd: true,
     method: 'get',
     treeField: 'text',
     idField: "oid",
     pagination: "true",
     fitColumns: "true",
     url: '/product_configurator/populate_sub_tree.json',
     columns: [
         [{
             field: 'quantity',
             title: 'Quantity',
             width: 100,
             editor: "numberbox",
             align: "right"
         }

         ]
     ],
     frozenColumns: [
         [{
             title: 'Name',
             field: 'text',
             width: 500
         }]
     ],

     onDblClickRow: function (row) {

         $(this).treegrid('beginEdit', row.oid);
     }
});`
```

Can any1 help me please!?

Comment: you can capture Enter event by keycode value 13..

Answer (score 0):

Try doing the following:

when you define the nodes as draggable, set their revert option to true. This means they will return to their existing position.

Then, modify the ondrop functionality so that it appends the source to the node you're targeting, like in the source of the drag and drop demo

```
onDrop:function(e,source){
                    if ($(source).hasClass('assigned')){
                        $(this).append(source);
                    } else {
                        var c = $(source).clone().addClass('assigned');
                        $(this).empty().append(c);
                        c.draggable({
                            revert:true
                        });
                    }
                }
```

This basically means your node will be returned to its original position after dragging stops, but wherever you stop dragging the node will be cloned and appended, and also made draggable again.

Comment: thnx swader..but hw can i set  revert : true for nodes as tree is getting populated from json? i m lil weak in trees:(

Comment: I am getting error :  Object #<Object> has no method 'cloneNode'

Comment: Could you give me the actual tree data so I can check it out on a live example?

Comment: sure..here is json that comes from serverside & creates tree : 
   `[{
  "id":2,
  "parent_id":0,
  "text": "Tumbler",
  "cls": "folder",
               "children": []
 },
 {
  "id":3,
  "parent_id":0,
  "text": "Plate",
  "cls": "folder",
  "children": []
 }]`